# Synchronise Pi clocks on a LAN with no Internet connection

Tags: pi-3, ntp

I'm setting up an installation where a small number of LAN connected Pis (model 3) will display a number of image slideshows, each on a separate display. As the images on each of the displays must appear and dissappear approximately at the same time I thought to use a global clock for synchronisation purposes

My issue is that it has been quite hard to find a concise guide on setting up a LAN clock across the various forums - for example I have found several references to setting up an NTP server on a PI but each tutorial seems to be slightly different than the next - on one only ntp.conf is edited, in another additional conf files are edited (dhcp) and in yet another it is mentioned that NTP is obsolete because the timesync service is now used.

I was wondering if someone could  please point me to a current and correct guide to setup a time server on my LAN so that the Pis on it can have the same time?

Comment: *"it is mentioned that NTP is obsolete because the timesync service"* -> `timesyncd` ( https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html) is NTP based so this is a bit fallacious; hopefully what was actually said was that the NTP client implementation had changed and `ntpd` was obsolete -- although I think this now applies to `timesyncd` as well in favour of `chronyd`, which is also NTP based.  Point being: **NTP is not going anywhere**.  It is a very widely (not just on Linux) used used system involving a global infrastructure...

Comment: ...2nd point being: If you configure a local NTP server (by any means), you can count on a client existing for it using pretty much any operating system worth the name.  So focus on that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So what should I use as server and client  mplementations to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Don't worry about the client, that's just a matter of finding out what it is and configuring it to use your server (shouldn't be too hard).  As for setting up a server, after looking around it is surprisingly hard to find information; I recommend you ask "How to set up an NTP server on Linux" on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  Personally I'd find it simpler to just bang out a simple UDP app because it would take me less time to code than to sift through NTP docs, if you have anyone like that around.

Comment: From the resources I'd found I got the impression that setting up a Pi as an NTP server was a simple affair... most tutorials included a modified ntp.conf file as "ntp server" and did not mention any other steps....so is there no Rasbian built-in support for something like this? Regarding your UDP app suggestion, what's the high level design behind this? I mean how would the pis synchronise through this?

Comment: You could be right about `ntp.conf`, I got that impression too, and looking at `man ntp.conf` supports this inference (without, unfortunately, clarifying it).  Since that `ntp` client is no longer used, you would need to start the server yourself. I don't see any systemd service covering it, but, gasp, it looks like `chronyd` can be used as an NTP server too: https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/ IMO then your best bet is to look into that (again, Unix & Linux will probably be a better source of information and help).

Comment: Indeed, lack of clarification on the subject was the reason I felt the need to write here. I will look into chronyd and see if I can use it, thanks for the pointers

Comment: `I have found several references to setting up an NTP server on a PI but` - and haven't tried to follow any?

Comment: Keep in mind that you probably have no real clock at all, without an RTC or internet time server. Simply rebooting all your pi’s at the sane time resets their clocks to the same default.

Comment: @JohnKeates *"Simply rebooting all your pi’s at the sane time resets their clocks to the same default"* -> This is not true unless you take steps to ensure it by writing to `/etc/fake-hwclock.data` at shutdown, which of course won't work if the power is cut, etc.  It is not a reliable alternative.

Comment: @JaromandaX As mentioned, the references I've found were lacking in clarity and in parts conflicted with each other. I prefer to have a solid base from which to start working on something instead of fumbling about and I thought that by asking this question here and mentioning the reason that I did so would be a good way forward

Comment: @JohnKeates Understood, the issue I'm worried about is that slowly a drift will creep in from all the micro lags - by having the same on all Pis I thought I could "reset" the sequence at specific time points thus preventing this drift from getting out of hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As goldilicks has pointed out `NTP` is alive and well, although Debian Stretch has adopted a simpler client `systemd-timesyncd.service`

You can restore `ntpd`, which can function as a server, but as I have not done this will refrain from attempting to explain - you may find https://digitalbarbedwire.com/2015/05/16/debianubuntu-systemd-ntp-and-something-called-timesyncd/ useful.

You would need to configure the other Pi to use this in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`

This seems like overkill; if I was running an isolated network I would use an inexpensive RTC - those based on DS3231 are at least an order of magnitude better than the system clock, and temperature stabilised.

An even simpler approach is to copy the date from the host by running `ssh pi@hostname.local sudo date -s$(date -Ins)` . This should synchronise the clocks, and could be run regularly using `chron`. I use this approach to synchronise clocks on systems without internet access.

Comment: The simple ssh approach you are suggesting may work for what I have in mind, I will look into it and provide feedback, thanks